# Create a Premium content section using WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I need to create a WordPress powered website that has a 'Premium' content section.

I want all content to be accessible, but after a visitor has looked at the Premium section, say 5 times, I want to ask them to register (name and email address) to continue viewing the Premium content.

I found a WordPress plugin called WP-Members, but it doesn't look like it can tell how many times a user has visited a certain section of the website.

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try a plugin like Wishlist members, It doesn' have the view limit for non-registered members, but you have shortcodes to define what logged in and non-logged in users can see.

Btw, it's not a good idea to limit users based on the views, what if they change their IP address or delete their cookies :)